# Async process start and wait for it to finish

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, process

I am new to the thread model in .NET. What would you use to:

1. Start a process that handles a file `(process.StartInfo.FileName = fileName;)`.
2. Wait for the user to close the process OR abandon the thread after some time.
3. If the user closed the process, delete the file.

Starting the process and waiting should be done on a different thread than the main thread, because this operation should not affect the application.

Example:

My application produces an html report. The user can right click somewhere and say "View Report" - now I retrieve the report contents in a temporary file and launch the process that handles html files i.e. the default browser. The problem is that I cannot cleanup, i.e. delete the temp file.

Comment: Console ap or WinForms or ASP.NET?

Comment: Console or WinForms. The process I am starting is local to the machine.

Comment: I have an example that uses async/await posted up here-- http://www.allampersandall.com/2013/03/net-process-async-await

Comment: You might be interested in [this post](http://www.codeducky.org/process-handling-net), which explains how to work with a Process using async/await and timeouts.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any async equivalent of Process.Start?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10788982/is-there-any-async-equivalent-of-process-start)

Comment: Marked as dupe of a newer question, that has more current, (and so, likely more relevant) answers

Comment: Over the years I've created a Class which is handling starting processes asyncronous with cancellation and other options for starting the process. [You could find the Class here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56091162/9758687)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The .NET 5 introduced the new API [`Process.WaitForExitAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexitasync), that allows to wait asynchronously for the completion of a process. It offers the same functionality with the existing [`Process.WaitForExit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit), with the only difference being that the waiting is asynchronous, so it does not block the calling thread.

Usage example:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filePath = Path.Combine
    (
        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData),
        Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".txt"
    );
    File.WriteAllText(filePath, "Hello World!");
    try
    {
        using Process process = new();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "Notepad.exe";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = filePath;
        process.Start();
        await process.WaitForExitAsync();
    }
    finally
    {
        File.Delete(filePath);
    }
    MessageBox.Show("Done!");
}
```

In the above example the UI remains responsive while the user interacts with the opened file. The UI thread would be blocked if the `WaitForExit` had been used instead.

Comment: If I would need this on lower versions of .NET, I would probably copy the source in an extension method. https://source.dot.net/#System.Diagnostics.Process/System/Diagnostics/Process.cs,b6a5b00714a61f06

Comment: @BogdanGavrilMSFT in case it's about starting one process only, I would probably prefer the dirty but safe `await Task.Run(() => process.WaitForExit());`. 

Comment: @TheodorZoulias No. That has zero advantage over the blocking call to `WaitForExit()`, with that additional overhead of `await`. That isn't safe. Don't do that.

Comment: @MarcL I am not sure what you are comparing. Are you saying that the asynchronous `Process.WaitForExitAsync` has zero advantage over the blocking `Process.WaitForExit`, and also that it's not safe?

Comment: I'm saying that `await Task.Run(<synchronous method>)` is not a good alternative, since it queues the work onto the ThreadPool. See [Stephen Cleary](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/taskrun-etiquette-and-proper-usage.html) for more details.

Comment: @MarcL what is a better alternative in your opinion, if you want the functionality of `Process.WaitForExitAsync` and you are targeting a NET platform older than .NET 5? The synchronous `Process.WaitForExit` blocks the UI thread, causing the UI to become non-responsive, so it's out of the question. You have to suggest something better.

Answer (score 61):

"and waiting must be async" - I'm not trying to be funny, but isn't that a contradiction in terms? However, since you are starting a `Process`, the `Exited` event may help:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = null;
Process process = Process.Start(startInfo);
process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
process.Exited += delegate {/* clean up*/};
```

If you want to actually wait (timeout etc), then:

```
if(process.WaitForExit(timeout)) {
    // user exited
} else {
    // timeout (perhaps process.Kill();)
}
```

For waiting async, perhaps just use a different thread?

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate {
    Process process = Process.Start(startInfo);
    if(process.WaitForExit(timeout)) {
        // user exited
    } else {
        // timeout
    }
});
```

Comment: I have a question. If i have a function  A() { ThreadPool.UnsafeQueueUserWorkItem((o) =>
            {
                ....
                proc.WaitForExit();
                ...
}
and in the main method I have like this : A(); Console.Write("aa"); for example... the thing is when console.write finish its work and the thread still didnt finish its work.. the page is loading. and its not waiting for the process to termine. what should i do ? Thanks guys

Comment: @Grace hard to say based just on that... but unless you *wait* for the worker thread, isn't that exactly what you would *expect* to see?

Comment: so i should wait for the thread to termine from the main method ?

Comment: @Grace that depends on what you are doing; if the *only* thing you are doing is waiting for a process to exit, then... why do that on a worker thread? Needs more context, basically. Otherwise I can't give a useful answer.

Comment: :my process converts files to .flv and plays them with javascript.. when i call the function without a Thread.Sleep() after it , i cant get the conversion nor the player bcoz the thread didnt have time to finish its work before the page load..butwhen i put a sleep after the function , thats when im getting my player.

Comment: @Grace you will need some kind of ajax/polling to handle that scenario if you don't want to block the original request; you can't just write to the old request when it has finished

Comment: If anyone is curious what `WaitForExit()` does, it simply uses a `WaitHandle` for its timeout

Comment: Hi @MarcGravell, a question. I've done the same, when I open a .ini file and then close it, everything is fine and file gets cleaned. But when I open a .jpg file the story becomes different, it looks like the process is not getting exitted at all and thus the file is not being gattered. If it helps, the process is null when I open a .jpg file, by the way, I am using the overload with (string filename) parameter. Any solution?

Answer (score 23):

Adding an advanced alternative to this old question.  If you want to wait for a process to exit without blocking any thread and still support timeouts, try the following:

```
    public static Task<bool> WaitForExitAsync(this Process process, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        ManualResetEvent processWaitObject = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        processWaitObject.SafeWaitHandle = new SafeWaitHandle(process.Handle, false);

        TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

        RegisteredWaitHandle registeredProcessWaitHandle = null;
        registeredProcessWaitHandle = ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(
            processWaitObject,
            delegate(object state, bool timedOut)
            {
                if (!timedOut)
                {
                    registeredProcessWaitHandle.Unregister(null);
                }

                processWaitObject.Dispose();
                tcs.SetResult(!timedOut);
            },
            null /* state */,
            timeout,
            true /* executeOnlyOnce */);

        return tcs.Task;
    }
```

Again, the advantage to this approach compared to the accepted answer is that you're not blocking any threads, which reduces the overhead of your app.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following code.

```
public void KickOffProcess(string filePath) {
  var proc = Process.Start(filePath);
  ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallBack(WaitForProc), proc);
}

private void WaitForProc(object obj) {
  var proc = (Process)obj;
  proc.WaitForExit();
  // Do the file deletion here
}
```

Comment: Not sure it handles the "OR abandon the thread after some time"

Answer (score 0):

I would probably not use a separate process for opening a file. Instead, I'd probably utilize a background thread (if I thought the operation was going to take a long time and possible block the UI thread).

```
private delegate void FileOpenDelegate(string filename);

public void OpenFile(string filename)
{
   FileOpenDelegate fileOpenDelegate = OpenFileAsync;
   AsyncCallback callback = AsyncCompleteMethod;
   fileOpenDelegate.BeginInvoke(filename, callback, state);
}

private void OpenFileAsync(string filename)
{
   // file opening code here, and then do whatever with the file
}
```

Of course, this is not a good working example (it returns nothing) and I haven't shown how the UI gets updated (you have to use BeginInvoke at the UI level because a background thread cannot update the UI thread). But this approach is generally how I go about handling asynchronous operations in .Net.

Comment: Sorry, actually I meant that the process should handle the file, not open it. I rewrote the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Exited` event in Process class

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();

info.FileName = "notepad.exe";
Process process = Process.Start(info);

process.Exited += new EventHandler(process_Exited);
Console.Read();
```

and in that event you can handle the operations you mentioned