# How do I mount a VHD using C# code without invoking a diskpart script?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, vhd

In my Azure role I want to mount a VHD - roughly have an equivalent of the following `diskpart` commands:

```
vdisk select VhdFilePath
vdisk attach
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2567199/57428) explains how to create a script and then programmatically invoke it from C#.

Is there a way to achieve the same without a script - just with some .NET classes?

Comment: You have to wrap the VHD API through P/Invoke.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if there's a managed API to do this, but there are a few examples of C# wrappers around some native methods:

http://www.jmedved.com/2009/05/open-and-attach/

And since this wraps around the [AttachVirtualDisk](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd323692%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method I assume it should also work for Windows Server 2008 R2 (note that you'll need to set the **osFamily** of your role to 2 in order to get the **R2**).