# WKHTMLTOPDF Hangs up for certain files from ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, wkhtmltopdf

I'm using wkhtmltopdf.exe file to create PDF files from my asp.net web application. But unfortunately for certain files the process continues to run for unlimitted and the application freezes. But the same html file I was able to convert using command prompt. I really doubts there is any file size limit for the html when converting from asp.net? Is it?

Other files from the same URL working without any issue using the converter. but certain large files failed from asp.net.
This is my code

```
  Dim fileContent As Byte() = Nothing

    Dim process As New System.Diagnostics.Process()
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True

    'set the executable location
    process.StartInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/bin/"), "wkhtmltopdf.exe")
    'set the arguments to the exectuable
    ' wkhtmltopdf [OPTIONS]... <input fileContent> [More input fileContents] <output fileContent>
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = "--margin-top 20 --margin-bottom 20 " + url + " d:\ssss\output.pdf"
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
    'run the executable
    process.Start()
    'Dim output As String = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
    'Dim buffer As Byte() = process.StandardOutput.CurrentEncoding.GetBytes(output)

    'wait until the conversion is done
    process.WaitForExit()

    ' read the exit code, close process    
    Dim returnCode As Integer = process.ExitCode
    process.Close()
```

After WaitForExit triggers its running for unlimitted or not getting stopped and seems to be the conversion is failed.

Comment: I suggest that you capture StandardError and StandardOutput and check what they contain, they might have important clues. It's already creating the PDF with another method so they propably won't contain the PDF binary.

Comment: Also, it would be great if we could get the same great file to see if it fails for us as well.

Comment: ALSO, use some kind of kill limit for the WaitForExit(). I sugggest putting like a 90 second limit with `process.WaitForExit(90000);` Then, when it fails you don't have to crash your program or wait for infinity, but you can get a nicer error and read the StandardError and StandardOutput. Something like the answers in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346651/how-to-use-process-waitforexit although I have not really tested them myself.

Comment: @Nenotlep Thanks mate.. Actually I already tried with the wait limit which only triggers the error when process.close executes. But honestly I didnt tried to check whats the standardoutput contains because I dont know how to check that.. Am not familiar with these applications where thirdparty exe's has to be executed from web application.. So requesting some support from you..

Comment: Yeah I wish I could help more, but I'm not very good at them myself. I hope it helps and shows something interesting, but I'm not very confident to be honest. Hopefully it will be even a little useful.

Comment: Yea.. its a nice stuff for free pdf creation.. But this memory problem becoming a headache... a real bottleneck since without expecting that I made that uploaded to live application..