# How can I stop async Process by CancellationToken?

Tags: c#, async-await, cancellation

I found beneath code for execute some process without freezing UI. This code is executed when 'Start Work' button is pressed. And I think users would stop this work by 'Stop' button. So I found this article at MSDN.. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155759.aspx . But, It was hard that applying this `CancellationToken` at this code.. Anyone can help this problem?

I use `public static async Task<int> RunProcessAsync(string fileName, string args)` method only.

Code (From https://stackoverflow.com/a/31492250):

```
public static async Task<int> RunProcessAsync(string fileName, string args)
{
    using (var process = new Process
    {
        StartInfo =
        {
            FileName = fileName, Arguments = args,
            UseShellExecute = false, CreateNoWindow = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true, RedirectStandardError = true
        },
        EnableRaisingEvents = true
    })
    {
        return await RunProcessAsync(process).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}

// This method is used only for internal function call.
private static Task<int> RunProcessAsync(Process process)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();

    process.Exited += (s, ea) => tcs.SetResult(process.ExitCode);
    process.OutputDataReceived += (s, ea) => Console.WriteLine(ea.Data);
    process.ErrorDataReceived += (s, ea) => Console.WriteLine("ERR: " + ea.Data);

    bool started = process.Start();
    if (!started)
    {
        //you may allow for the process to be re-used (started = false) 
        //but I'm not sure about the guarantees of the Exited event in such a case
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not start process: " + process);
    }

    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    process.BeginErrorReadLine();

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Usage :

```
var cancelToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
int returnCode = async RunProcessAsync("python.exe", "foo.py", cancelToken.Token);
if (cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested) { /* something */ }
```

When the start button clicked, it starts some python script. 
When script is running and user wants to stop it, user presses stop button.
Then program executes below code.

```
cancelToken.Cancel();
```

Thank you very much for reading this question.

Comment: Can I know why my question gave that -1 without any answer or comments?

Comment: What do you want the `CancellationToken` to do? Kill the process?

Comment: @StephenCleary: Thank you for comment! Yes, What I want to do is Terminate program immediately.

Comment: This question is not clear at all. There's not even a `CancellationToken` in the code you posted! Never mind do I see any sort of problem statement, other than maybe "it was hard". Please provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces whatever problem you are having. Also provide a precise description of your problem: explain what the code does now and what you want it to do instead.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I added some short usage code. Thanks for advise!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite simple now:

```
process.WaitForExitAsync(token);
```

Comment: `await process.WaitForExitAsync(token);` for completeness

Comment: In the comments, the OP indicated that the cancellation should result in the external process being terminated, which constitutes the meat of @svick's answer. Cancelling the token passed to `WaitForExitAsync()` _will not_ kill the external process, it just stops the currently running program from waiting for it. The `CancellationTokenRegistration` described above is still required.

Answer (score 24):

The simple answer is that you can just call `process.Kill()` when the token is canceled:

```
cancellationToken.Register(() => process.Kill());
```

But there are two problems with this:

1. If you attempt to kill a process that doesn't exist yet or that has already terminated, you get an `InvalidOperationException`.
2. If you don't `Dispose()` the `CancellationTokenRegistration` returned from `Register()`, and the `CancellationTokenSource` is long-lived, you have a memory leak, since the registrations will stay in memory as long as the `CancellationTokenSource`.

Depending on your requirements, and your desire for clean code (even at the cost of complexity) it may be okay to ignore problem #2 and work around problem #1 by swallowing the exception in a `catch`.

Comment: Should the call to the Register() method come before are after the call to process.Start()? How about in relation to the call to the Exited event? Can post as a separate question if recommended. My example is like your answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10788982/is-there-any-async-equivalent-of-process-start/31492250#31492250

Comment: you can also do the same this with less parenthesis: *cancellationToken.Register(process.Kill);*