# Disposing a CancellationTokenRegistration registered to kill a Process started in an async method

Tags: c#, async-await, cancellation, cancellation-token

I'm using an `async` method to start a `Process` (to call `raspistill`). The code is pretty standard, but like the developer in this question: [How can I stop async Process by CancellationToken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34199628/how-can-i-stop-async-process-by-cancellationtoken), I'd like to be able to cancel the process with a `CancellationToken`. As an example, one of my ASP.NET core API endpoints starts a MJPEG stream that will need to be closed.

I've taken on board the answer to the above question, and written the following ProcessRunner class:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using NLog;

namespace RabbieCam.Utils
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Run process as asynchronous task.
    /// </summary>
    public static class ProcessRunner
    {
        private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        /// <summary>
        /// Run process as asynchronous task.
        /// </summary>
        public static async Task<int> RunProcessAsync(string fileName, 
                                                      string args,
                                                      CancellationToken token)
        {
            CancellationTokenRegistration registration;
            using (var process = new Process
            {
                StartInfo =
                {
                    FileName = fileName, 
                    Arguments = args,
                    UseShellExecute = false, 
                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true, 
                    RedirectStandardError = true
                },
                EnableRaisingEvents = true
            })
            {
                var exitCode = await RunProcessAsync(
                    process,
                    token,
                    out registration
                ).ConfigureAwait(false);

                logger.Debug($"Process {fileName} ended");

                registration.Dispose();

                logger.Debug("Registration disposed");

                return exitCode;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Run process asynchronously.
        /// </summary>
        private static Task<int> RunProcessAsync(
            Process process,
            CancellationToken token,
            out CancellationTokenRegistration registration
        )
        {
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();

            process.Exited += (s, ea) => tcs.SetResult(process.ExitCode);
            // process.OutputDataReceived += (s, ea) => // TODO if needed
            // process.ErrorDataReceived += (s, ea) => // TODO if needed

            registration = token.Register(() => 
                {
                    try
                    {
                        process.Kill();
                    }
                    catch (InvalidOperationException e)
                    {
                        logger.Error($"Failed to kill process: {e.Message}");
                    }
                }
            );

            bool started = process.Start();
            if (!started)
            {
                registration.Dispose();
                throw new InvalidOperationException(
                    "Could not start process: " + process
                );
            }

            process.BeginOutputReadLine();
            process.BeginErrorReadLine();

            return tcs.Task;
        }
    } 
}
```

My question is will this dispose the `registration` as desired once the process has ended or been cancelled?

Also is there a better solution to the problem?

I guess also is the CancellationTokenSource disposed after the ASP.NET API request is completed? If that is the case it may not be necessary to clean up the registration.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a unit(ish) test and it seems the code posted above does work as expected. I see the debug statements when I cancel the process and the registration is disposed.

```
public class TestProcessRunner
{   
    [Fact]
    public void TestRegistrationDisposedOnCancel()
    {
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var token = cts.Token;

        string fileName = "ping";
        string args = "google.com";

        var task = ProcessRunner.RunProcessAsync(fileName, args, token);
        cts.Cancel();
        task.Wait();
    }
}
```