# How do I end a process that was started with ProcessStartInfo?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to end a process that I started with a ProcessStartInfo, here's the code to start it

```
public class MyProcess
{
    void OpenWithStartInfo()
    {
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        startInfo.FileName = "C:/StartBot.bat";
        Process.Start(startInfo);
    }

    public static void Start()
    {
        MyProcess myProcess = new MyProcess();
        myProcess.OpenWithStartInfo();
    }
    public static void End()
    {
               
    }
}
```

I want to end the process that I started with my End() function, but I have no idea how to go about doing that. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1) Look at this post, how start a process asynchronously:  [Is there any async equivalent of Process.Start?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10788982/is-there-any-async-equivalent-of-process-start).    2) And the following post how to stop a process: [How can I stop async Process by CancellationToken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34199628/how-can-i-stop-async-process-by-cancellationtoken)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I kill a process using Vb.NET or C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116090/how-do-i-kill-a-process-using-vb-net-or-c)

Answer (score 1):

`Process.Start` returns a `Process` that you can call `Kill()` on assuming your store the reference somewhere:

```
    public class MyProcess
    {
        Process process;
        void OpenWithStartInfo()
        {
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
            startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            startInfo.FileName = "C:/StartBot.bat";
            process = Process.Start(startInfo);
        }

        static MyProcess myProcess = new MyProcess();

        public static void Start()
        {
            myProcess.OpenWithStartInfo();
        }
        public static void End()
        {
            myProcess.process.Kill();
        }
    }
```