# Task async and await

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, async-await

I want the method PrintOrderAsync to execute an external EXE to print an order.
The code for method PrintOrderAsync does not show any syntax errors

```
public async Task<string> PrintOrderAsync(string PrintExe, string ExePath, int nOrderNo)
{
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Process.Start(ExePath + PrintExe, nOrderNo.ToString()));

        return "";
 }
```

But I am struggling with the syntax for the calling method.  Here is what I tried:

```
Task<string> result = PrintOrderAsync(PrintExe, ExePath, nOrderNo);
```

And I see syntax error on the above line.  What am I missing?

Comment: Why would you choose to use `StartNew`? Did you see that as an example somewhere?

Comment: @StephenCleary  Yes, I did see this somewhere.  But I am listening and if you think the code should work better with changes, please let me know.

Comment: @StephenCleary  Now that you asked the question, I am trying to see how I can change/optimize the line with StartNew and cannot figure this out. Obviously you see something wrong with my syntax so I need to learn how to make it work better.

Comment: @Hidalgo, are you really happy with fire-and-forget semantics of `Process.Start`? Any particular reason you're not calling `WaitForExit` on the returned `Process` instance?

Comment: Look at the answers in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10788982/is-there-any-async-equivalent-of-process-start) question using TaskCompletionSource for a better implementation

Comment: Kirill, the goal of my syntax is to start the external program (which prints an order) and continue the process, without waiting for printing to finish. Therefore, the term "fire-and-forget" does seem to apply to what I want.
Do I understand that "waitForExit" would wait for printing to finish, before process continues?

Comment: Jeroen,  Thank you for the link. I have read it but still not see how to make it a "better implementation."

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: @svick  I am not getting an error.  Initially I was getting the error pointing to the fact that I missed the key word "static".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the code that you have shared here you are starting a process. This is concerning as you are not actually waiting for the result of the process, in fact -- it is fire and forget regardless of the `async` and `await` keywords unless you wait for the process to exit. There are several ways to do this:

```
public static Task WaitForExitAsync(this Process process, 
    int milliseconds,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{    
    return Task.Run(() => process.WaitForExit(milliseconds), cancellationToken);
}
```

For example, here is an extension method you could use to wrap the waiting for the process in a `Task`. It could then be awaited like this:

```
public async Task PrintOrderAsync(string PrintExe, string ExePath, int nOrderNo)
{
    return Process.Start(ExePath + PrintExe, nOrderNo.ToString())
                  .WaitForExitAsync(5000);
}

// Then you could await it wherever...
await PrintOrderAsync(PrintExe, ExePath, nOrderNo);
```

Alternatively, if you do not want to wait for it to complete (i.e.; you want fire and forget, like you have now) do this:

```
Process.Start(ExePath + PrintExe, nOrderNo.ToString())
```

Do not wrap it in a `Task` or anything, it is an entirely separate process anyways (personally, I prefer the first option I shared).

Comment: David, First thank you for the post and code.  Something confuses me (and it is me, of course).  If I don't use async and await at all (as you pointed) and simply start the process with 
Process.Start( ExePath + PrintExt, nOrderNo.ToString()), wouldn't this process start on the same thread as the "main" code and wouldn't the "main" code have to wait for process to finish?  That is, I thought that the reason to use async and await is to "move" the Process to a new thread and therefore "free" the "main" thread to continue.   False logic? :)

Comment: Not at all, it starts a new process that is entirely disconnected from your code that started it. Try this, write a simple console application that does `Process.Start("notepad")`. And immediately exit the console app -- notepad remains open and is started in its own process -- in fact these two processes cannot share threads at all.

Comment: David, thank you very much.  You are right.  Hopefully the entire exercise of learning how to use async and await has not been a complete waste of time and I will get to use it at some point.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
string result = await PrintOrderAsync(PrintExe, ExePath, nOrderNo);
```

Comment: M Tovbin, I admit that I know almost nothing about the topic I brought up here.  Therefore, I don't know what would be the difference in using your syntax vs. the 
await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Process.Start
But thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: when you do an await Task.Factory.StartNew it spins up a new thread and executes your Process.Start on that thread.  When it spins up a new thread, the current thread is freed.  This is fine if that is what you are attempting to do.  Since your PrintOrderAsync method returns a Task of string, you have to await the PrintOrderAsync when making a call to it and assign the result to a string variable.

Comment: M Tovbin, thank you very much for the explanation.  But when I change my code "Task<string> result = PrintOrderAsync(PrintExe, ExePath, nOrderNo);"  with your code "string result = await PrintOrderAsync(PrintExe, ExePath, nOrderNo);" the VS shows the following error:
"The await operator can only be used within an async method. Consider making this method with 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'"

Comment: When you use an await inside a method, that method must be marked as async.  If it's not a delegate, it should also return a Task and should be awaited all the way up the chain.  When using async/await, you need to use it all the way up the chain.  If the method is not a delegate and you leave it as async void, your error handling will not work as you would expect it.