# How to automatically run command line program several times?

Tags: command-line, command-prompt

I have a c# program, integrated with a command line program. I want to run the command line program twice(start, finish, start again, finish again). Now I use a timer to set a special time period for every run, for example, give first run 10 seconds, no matter it is finished or not, after 10 seconds, the program starts the second run.

I want the second run can run automatically after the fist run finshed, How to do it? How to detect the first run is finished, and then take a trigger to start the second run?

Comment: Any code snippet will help us....

Comment: Do you want to run one instance of the `c#` program which executes a batch twice, or a `cmd` program` that runs your `c#` program twice, each waiting for the first target program to finish beore the second is started?

Answer (score 1):

Assume you run the command line as a process, see this answer to check if the process has finished:
[Find out if a process finished running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14709241/find-out-if-a-process-finished-running)

```
if (process.WaitForExit(timeout)) 
{
    // user exited
} else {
    // timeout (perhaps process.Kill();)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In a command line you can launch this command:

`start "" /w` will execute the command and wait until it is finished before proceeding.

```
for %a in (1 2) do start "" /w "programA.exe"
```