# C# gracefully close a separate application that has no UI

Tags: c#, c++, process

I use the c# process class to open a separate application that has no GUI. it is s a c++ project that I use the `Process.Kill()` on to end it. The problem is this doesn't give it a chance to finish its actions. `Process.Close()` just releases the object in my main app and and leaves the separate application running.

Whats the best way to make this process close gracefully?

Comment: The class should have a Dispose() method that performs cleanup and closes any objects that needs to be closed (or stop running).

Comment: I think you should not use Process.Kill(). Rather send message(udp...) between two applications and when completed its actions kill.

Comment: [Also some example for async:](http://stackoverflow.com/a/611127/3060520)

Comment: @jdweng You do realize that what you say has nothing to do with the topic?

Comment: @Sam The most important question here is: Is the C++ project also your project? Do you have access to the source code? If you can modify the tool: there are many options for inter process communication starting with UDP communication over TCP communcation to named pipes. If found it easy in the past to design my tools so I could send commands to them on standard input. Then, in C#, write a "close" command to the standard input of the tool so the tool knows it should quit.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar yes i can add to this c++ project if i wish. Any communication between the 2 projects would be advantageous if the time to develop is not too high.

Comment: Also to note is that i could have multiple copies of the c++ started by my main app at any given time. Meaning i would only want to close specific instances and not all at once.

Comment: Note that named pipes are unix specific.  Windows Events might also be a suitable mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past I needed to start a non-gui C# tool from a GUI C# tool, both of which I had written. I used the standard input/output streams to communicate between both tools.

You could make your C++ tool listen on its `stdin` for a command that indicates the tool should quit gracefully. Then, in your C# application, send the quit command, wait for a reasonable amount of time and if the tool hasn't ended by then, kill it.

I'm sorry that my C++ is not good enough to give you an example for the C++ side, but the following lines are used in my C# project to tell the external process to end:

```
m_consoleProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine("QUIT");
m_consoleProcess.WaitForExit(10000);
if (!m_consoleProcess.HasExited)
{
     m_consoleProcess.Kill();
}
```

If you need to manage separate external processes, of course you need to store one `Process` instance for each of them and you have to handle the case that the external process was ended before your application should quit.